# How to save values from option to one array cell in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So I got a loop of processes. You can check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/montel388/vPatQ/138/). 
So the point is my system can have different number of processes. And for each process there can be more than one studio. What I want to achieve is to save studios under one process into one array cell divided by coma. So later I could use this array and split studios to insert it to database.

My save function:

```
var LISTOBJ = {
saveList: function() {
$(".output").html("");
$(".studio").each(function() {
  var listCSV = [];
  $(this).find("input").each(function() {
    listCSV.push($(this).text());
  });
  var values = '' + listCSV.join(',') + '';
  $(".output").append("<input type='text' name='studio[]' value='" + values + "' />");
  $("#output").append("<p>" + values + "</p>");
  console.debug(listCSV);
});
```

}
}

But it seems it doesnt work. What do I need to change to achieve what i want? Thank you

Comment: At first glance. You should move your "var listCSV = []" outside (before) your each loop.

Comment: what is your expected output? it seems your question is too broad

Comment: @JacobPaulozz I want to studios under each processes to be stored in same array cell later.  For example, I have an droppable area where user can drag and drop names. So as with studios this area is under each process. after saving and proceeding to next page I will get this `Array ( [0] => , xaaronjames, xaaronkoh [1] => , xbarikan, xbenny ) ` You can view example  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/montel388/ow29t4t7/24/). But function is a bit different. So what I what I want is for example to be able to get smth like this: `Array ( [0] => ,APEX, BASECAMP [1] => , CANVAS,  ORBIT) `

Answer (score 1):

on html file, on process 1 select option add this to the class attribute process-1, and on the process 2 also add process-2 on class attribute then, modify the saveList function

```
  var processList = {process_1 : [] , process_2 : []};
  $(".output").html("");
  $(".studio").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    var process1 = $(this).hasClass('process-1');
    var process2 = $(this).hasClass('process-2');
    if(text) {
        listCSV.push(text);
        if(process1) {
            processList.process_1.push(text);
        } else if (process2) {
            processList.process_2.push(text);
        }
    }
});
listObj.saveList = listCSV;
var values = listCSV.join(', ');
$(".output").append("<input type='text' name='studio[]' value='" + values + "' />");
$("#output").append("<p>" + values + "</p>");
console.log(processList);
```

Comment: The thing is fiddle is just an example. In my system there is no process 1 and 2. there are maybe up to 10 processes. the number of processes depends on user's input.

Comment: ahh okay, but for me that is the efficient way to make it easier.

Comment: So, is there any way to use save function in loop?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean i cant add to each process class process_1 and process_2 etc. cuz i dont know how many processes gonna be there. Because it is a loop

Answer (score 0):

ahh, i think i have solved the first question, about the question #1. on your html file add value attribute on each option. and also remove the div class="studio" hence put the class "studio" on the select class. after that try my code on the javascript file

```
 // everytime the save button is clicked
 $('#savebutton').click(function() {
    saveList();
 });
 // set list studio
 var listCSV = [];
 // your list object
 var listObj = {saveList: []};
 // save list function
 function saveList() {
    $(".output").html("");
    $(".studio").each(function() {
      var text = $(this).val();
      if(text) {
            listCSV.push(text);
      }
   });
   listObj.saveList = listCSV;
   var values = listCSV.join(', ');
   $(".output").append("<input type='text' name='studio[]' value='" + values + "' />");
   $("#output").append("<p>" + values + "</p>");
 }
```

Comment: I tried it saves only studios from process 1. See edited [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/montel388/vPatQ/142/)

Comment: yes it is because you forgot to add also on the process 2

Comment: Ok, I've tried it and now it saves all studios in one array cell. `Array ( [0] => APEX, BASECAMP, TOONIGAMI ) ` But I've expected it to be `Array ( [0] => APEX, BASECAMP  [1] => TOONIGAMI ) `